# Editable list of string

Tags: angular, input, angular8, angular-ngmodel

I need editable array of string: user must be able to add/remove/edit any number of strings.

My solution works for array of objects but not for array of string.

Please explain to me - why does input lose focus on each character?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Foo { str: string; } ;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<p> Notes:{{notes | json}} </p>
<p> Objects:{{objects | json}} </p>

<button (click)="addItem()" >Add new</button> 
 input loses
<p>Objects:</p>
<div *ngFor="let obj of this.objects; let i = index;" >

    Works :<input [(ngModel)]="objects[i].str"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >

</div>

<p>Notes:</p>
<div *ngFor="let str of this.notes; let i = index;" >

  It does not work because it loses focus:<input [(ngModel)]="notes[i]"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >

</div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private notes: string[]=[];
  private objects: Foo[]=[];

  addItem() {
    this.notes.push('');
    this.objects.push({str: ''});
  }
}
```

Stackblitz link: https://angular-tjm8hj.stackblitz.io/

And what needs to be fixed to make it work as expected? Thank you

Comment: Because every time you insert a character, the string in the array is replaced by a new one, so Angular deletes the corresponding DOM element corresponding to that element (in thr ngFor loop) and replaces it by a new one. You need to use trackBy. or, as you're doing in your first example, use mutable objects.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet, adding 'trackBy' solved the problem.